# Getting error AADSTS50020 when trying to run Azure Tailspin sample application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I am making my first steps with Azure, trying to figure out how difficult it would be to spin up a mISV business where I would sell subscriptions to my app running in Azure (SaaS model).

To that end, I am trying to run the 
[Tailspin sample application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/tailspin)
following instructions described 
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/run-the-app).

To run the application, at least two Azure Active directories are needed. One AD belongs to the fictitious Tailspin software provider (in this case, me). The Tailspin Web application and the accompanying WebAPI are registered in this directory. Other AD belongs to a customer (in this case, again me). Customers sign up for the application.

I have a single Azure subscription, so I was forced to set things up like this:

- I have registered Tailspin Web application and WebAPI in my Default AD. (<strike>I guess I could have created a specific AD for this purpose, but it was not strictly necessary.</strike>). The app and the API had to be created in this AD because they consume resources, and resources require a subscription. Putting the app and the API in a separate AD would require a separate Azure subscription.
- I have marked both the Web app and the API as Multi-tenant (so that they can appear in other ADs after customer sign-up).
- I have created another AD called TaiispinClient1 (the name is not important), with the idea to use it as a "customer" AD.
- In TailspinClient1 AD I have created a guest user using one of my external email addresses. I could not create a regular AD user because creating regular users requires having a validated web domain and I did not want to go through validation at this point.
- I have made sure that my guest user is every bit an admin user as the regular one:

  - In User Settings for the TailspinClient1 AD, "Users can register applications" is set to Yes (default)
  - In "Manage external collaboration settings", "Guest users permissions are limited" is set to No
  - My guest user has administrative directory roles (specifically, "Global administrator" and "Application administrator")

To resume, I ended up having two ADs in a single Azure subscription: the Default AD with the multi-tenant-enabled Tailspin app/API in it, 
and the TailspinClient1 AD with an admin user (albeit external).

I am running the Tailspin application locally.

When I try to sign up to the application as the admin user from the TailspinClient1 AD, I am getting the following error message after I (successfully) authenticate myself:

> AADSTS50020: User account <my TailspinClient1 admin user> from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application <GUID of my Tailspin Web app> in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

That message would have made sense had I forgotten to mark my Tailspin app/API as Multi-tenant, which I did not.

What am I missing here? Is this particular setup supported at all? Do I need to establish trust between those two ADs somehow?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can create regular users in AAD without a custom domain. You just need to use the default domain that's like tenantname.onmicrosoft.com.

Comment: Tried that, but I was getting an error saying that <my main tenantname>.onmicrosoft.com is not a validated domain. Now when I think about it, it could be that the reason was because I did not have any users in my main tenant... I will try again to create a regular user, to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Check that it's correct, you can see the hostname under "Custom domain names" in the main Azure Active Directory blade.

Comment: I took the custom domain (tenant) name from that blade, and tried again creating a regular user in Tailspin1Client AD using @<that domain/tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com. Still getting the error message "'<domain/tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com' is not a verified domain name in this directory". (I was able to create a user in the Default directory using that domain name.)